# No dot (aka period, full stop) at end of formatted bibliographic reference

Tags: custom-bib

I have used `latex makebst` to create a customised bibliography style. However, I am missing a period at the end of the bibliographic references. How can I modify the .bst file to include the period at the end?

[image: Missing dot at end of reference]

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE.

Answer (score 1):

In between the questions

```
`IN' WITH JOURNAL NAMES (if using 'in' with collections)
```

and

```
ABBREVIATE WORD `PAGES' (if not using external language file)
```

the `makebst` utility should have asked you the following question:

```
FINAL PUNCTUATION:
(*) Period at very end of the listed reference
(x) No period at end 
  Select:
```

Observe that the default choice is to insert a period at the end of each formatted entry. Judging by your query, though, you appear to have chosen the second option, `(x) No period at end`.

How to recover from this depends on whether or not you saved the dbj file. If you did, you could hand-edit the file to modify the choice for the `FINAL PUNCTUATION` question, which will probably look like this:

```
%FINAL PUNCTUATION:
%   %: (def) Period at very end
  fin-bare,%: No period at end
```

Just comment out the `fin-bare` line, save the dbj file, and rerun latex on the dbj file to recreate the bst file. If, however, you did *not* save the dbj file, you'll have to re-run the `makebst` utility from scratch.

Comment: Hi Micro. Thank you for your prompt reply. Yes, I did save the .dbj file.  How can I re-run latex on the dbj file after hand editing? Do I need to simply type in CMD the command "latex <name of dbj file> ?

Comment: @JonathanCassar - Yes. :-) Just be sure to include the `.dbj` extension. E.g., if the dbj file's full name is, say, `main.dbj`, be sure to enter `pdflatex main.dbj` on the command line.

Comment: It worked. Thanks Mico.

Comment: @JonathanCassar - You’re welcome! If you feel that my answer fully addressed your question, please feel free to “accept” it by clicking on the checkmark symbol. ;-)